# ‘gtk_widget_override_font’ is deprecated

Tags: gtk, pango, genie

I'm starting to use Genie with Pango + Gtk.

I want to change the text style of a label with Pango, but both modify_font and override_font are deprecated.

What is the alternative for this code using Pango?

```
uses Gtk
uses Pango

init 
    Gtk.init (ref args)
    var TestGtk = new Ventana()
    TestGtk.show_all()  
    Gtk.main()

class Ventana : Window      
    init        
        title = "Test Genie + Pango"
        default_width = 500     
        default_height = 200        
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER 
        destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit)

        var etiqueta = new Label("Hola Genie + Pango")      

        var fontdesc = new Pango.FontDescription()
        fontdesc.set_family("Purisa")
        fontdesc.set_size((int)(24 * Pango.SCALE))

        //etiqueta.modify_font(fontdesc)    // funciona pero OBSOLETO desde v 3.0
        etiqueta.override_font(fontdesc)    // funciona pero OBSOLETO desde v 3.16      

        add (etiqueta)
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use the Markup. I think is more correct.

Answer (score 1):

For a GtkLabel, you use [`gtk_label_set_attributes()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-set-attributes) and using an [attribute list](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html) instead of a font descriptor. You can either turn your existing font descriptor into an attribute list or use a single [font descriptor attribute](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html#pango-attr-font-desc-new) with the existing font descriptor.

As for other widgets, some widgets allow you to specify a Pango attribute list or font descriptor directly; check their documentation. For all others, use CSS.

Comment: Links don't work the answer doesn't explain how to use an attribute list with a font description.